# Objective C Arithmetic failing

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber

I have a `NSNumber` and when I try to do basic arithmetic it fails.

```
NSNumber *contentExpirationInDays = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1];
```

When I try to do a basic multiplication to convert to seconds it gives me crazy numbers:

```
NSTimeInterval contentExpirationInSecs =  [contentExpirationInDays intValue] * 24 * 60 * 60;
```

---

Note: The next bit is now irrelevant as explained in some answers:

*When I run the following commands in the console I get the following results:*

```
(lldb) po [contentExpirationInDays intValue]
1

(lldb) po [contentExpirationInDays intValue] * 2
-148319360
```

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the information regarding po vs p. I didn't know that detail...

So here is the real problem that I am experiencing:

```
NSNumber *contentExpirationInDays = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
NSTimeInterval contentExpiration = ([contentExpirationInDays intValue] * 24 * 60 * 60);
myObj.expirationDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:contentExpiration];
```

`obj.expirationDate` usually ends up with many years in the future or many years in the past instead of one day ahead of today.

Comment: `po` is "print object". Use `p` to print integers or other scalar values.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? Works perfectly fine on my Xcode 8.

Comment: This works for me, too, if I remove the extra `[` after the assignment (`=`) in the first line. However, the date calculation is a little bit naive.

Answer (score 1):

**po** is asking the debugger to **print** the description of the **object** at the address specified by the given pointer. As Martin R said, use **p** instead for just printing out scalar values:

```
p [contentExpirationInDays intValue] * 2
```

Answer (score -1):

NSNumber is a base class for objects which represent numbers, not a primitive scalar value such as a int or float.

If you need your number as an object, use NSDecimalNumber instead. Otherwise just leave it as a scalar type.

Comment: He converts it to a scalar using `-intValue`.